# Why Curry Redux Middleware: state => next => action {} vs. (state, next) => action {}

Tags: javascript, redux, middleware

After reading both [Redux's documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) on middleware and [source code](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.js) on applyMiddleware, I don't understand why middleware need the curry syntax:

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  return result
}
```

Couldn't the same thing be achieved by doing

```
const logger = (store, next) => action => {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  return result
}
```

Making the compose call in [applyMiddleware](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.js):

```
dispatch = compose(...middleware)(middlewareAPI , store.dispatch)
```

Comment: It *could*, but it would probably look more confusing because of the mix. Also, is `applyMiddleware` the only place where a `logger` might be used?

Comment: Idk about it looking confusing @Bergi, I can explain it to myself and others better saying a middleware takes a store and the next method it needs to call, and it returns result from next(). This also makes it similar to `express.js`

Comment: But what if you have to explain that it takes a store and next method together and then returns a function that takes an action and… You still have a curried function, and by *mixing* the curried style with the tuple style you will get confusion, and the question why not simply everything was curried.

Comment: Haha because it's like a function that returns a function that returns a function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A discussion with Dan Abramov can be found [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/534#issuecomment-131871893) regarding this. He said,

> We could have made it (store, next) => action => () but I don't see a
>   problem with just going all the way. You might want some configuration
>   later, at which point options => (store, next) => action => () looks
>   kinda arbitrary.

So no, it is not necessary to curry the parameters.

Comment: They could have required middle ware functions to be any kind of store, next, action receiving function, curried or not. The reason why it's store=>next=>action is probably because it's [signature is easier to compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58287349/1641941)

Answer (score 0):

No, because it a way to defer an function to be executed later. ()=>() returns a function object which only get executed later when the func obj is called.

Comment: const logger = (store, next) => action => { .. } is still a deferred function.